# JSON Schema for Array of Map<String,String[]> ; properties like key and value pairs

Tags: json, jsonschema

JSON contains run time key and value pairs

```
{
  "user_id" : 2
  "applicationName": "RetailPos",
  "permissions": {

  "Purchase": [
    "Access",
    "Create",
    "Delete",
    "Modify"
   ],
  "Sales": [
    "Access",
    "Create",
    "Delete",
    "Modify"
   ]
  },
 "group": "Admin Group"
}
```

consider the above sample, here `Purchase` and `Sales` are Targets and values `Access`,`Create`... are operations. Here both Targets and operations are run time values.

In this [JSON Schema Validation](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.5.22) couldnt find enough samples to create required schema.

```
{
"required": true,
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema",
"type": "object",
"properties": {
     "user_id": {
        "type": "number",
        "required": true
    },
     "application_name": {
      "type":"string",
      "required":true
    },

    //Permission schema

    "group" : {
      "type" :"string",
      "required":true
    }
  }
}
```

Any documentation or related samples would be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the "additionalProperties" keyword.
For example:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
     "user_id": {
        "type": "number",
        "required": true
    },
     "applicationName": {
      "type":"string",
      "required":true
    },   
    "permissions": {
      "additionalProperties": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": ["Access", "Create", "Delete", "Modify"]
        },
       }
     },

    "group" : {
      "type" :"string",
      "required":true
    }
  }
}
```

More info [here](https://github.com/json-schema/json-schema/wiki/Additionalproperties) and [here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-fge-json-schema-validation-00#section-5.4.4)

Comment: additionalProperties could be any but here there is a specific definition

Comment: @vels4j is something missing ?